# Adding row titles for Excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel

hoping someone could guide me in solving something I am stuck on. Below is the code I have created to export specific columns from an excel file and to save the exported file in a specific location on the drive. What I am stuck is on adding rows to the exported excel file.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import panda as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

df.pd.read_excel(file_path, usecols=['date','time']

#below attempts would have been inputted at this point before the save function 

path_to_save = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaulttextextension='.xlsx)
df.to_excel(path_to_save, index=False)
```

I have tried doing this with:
`df.insert('Exported By:')` - #this removes the data I have extracted and saves a blank excel file.

I went on and tried:

```
data = {'Exported by:':['']} #the idea for the blank space is because I want to be able to print out the excel file and manually write the item number as it changes for each excel file
df = pd.DataFrame(data) #But this didn't work and gave me an error
```

I'm stuck on this problem and can't seem to find a way to get this solved and not sure if I am doing something wrong within the code, any suggestions would be great!

The original file dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfCSa.png)

The exported file dataset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73wS4.png)

In image above I also added the addition of the rows that I would like to add to the above script.

Comment: Before saving your dataframe to an excel file, you can always create the dataframe with the data, and then do `df.columns = [a list of your column titles]`

Comment: I've tried to do something like that but it adds a column and I want to push the exported data down by adding a row and name the columns from the added row, and not sure how to do that without deleting the data exported.

Comment: Perhaps you can give a sample data for us to know how we can help you?

Comment: Hi Kevin, not sure if this is what you meant but I have added some images to outline the original file and what I would like to have an an output with the addition of the top 2 rows for manual input once printed out. Really appreciate the support on this!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this using the `df.loc[] = new row` function, where I defined a new row.
I am also trying to merge specific cells together and have been trying to use the `df.merge_cells` function but get an error saying ''DataFrame' object attribute 'merge_cells'' - slightly stuck on solving this one if anyone has an suggestions?